# How to temporarily disable iptables rule?

Tags: linux, firewall, lan, iptables

Typically I'm using MikroTik embeded routers, they're basing on Linux so their firewall settings feel pretty much 1:1 the same as iptables, just commands are a bit different but mechanics the same. Some more advance MTK firewall functionality with raw iptables can be achieved using `-m` extensions - like connection states or comments for example.

I can't find disable option in raw iptables. Is there any iptables extension that allows to temporarily disable iptables rules?

By temporarily I mean disabling rule without actually removing it from table so that it's still visible in `iptables -L` but not functional. In MTK you can type something like `set 40 disabled=yes` and then later `set 40 disabled=no`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this in raw `iptables`. You can only add/delete/modify rule.

You can achieve similar functionality by changing target of rule to nothing (don't specify `-j`). But to do this, you must write again the whole rule and new rule still will be processed (matched; but no action will be done).